# How to specify multiple filters for NLog logging rule in appsettings.json

Tags: .net-core, nlog

I've seen examples of multiple when filters using XML but I'm using appsettings.json for all configuration.  I've been able to implement a single when filter but when I try to add an additional filter I get a duplicate key error.  Any ideas?

This works -

```json
"rules": [
  {
    "logger": "*",
    "minLevel": "Debug",
    "writeTo": "db",
    "filters": {
      "when": { 
        "condition": "equals('${event-properties:sublevel}','diagnostic')",
        "action": "Ignore"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/issues/491

Comment: If you update to NLog 4.7.9 and use the configuration shown in the answer, then it will work with NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.7.1

Answer (score 6):

This limitation has been fixed with NLog.Extensions.Logging 1.7.2, that now supports this working example:

```json
"rules": [
    {
        "logger": "*",
        "minLevel": "Trace",
        "writeTo": "Console",
        "filterDefaultAction": "Log",
        "filters": [
            {
                "type": "when",
                "condition": "equals('${event-properties:sublevel}','diagnostic')",
                "action": "Ignore"
            },
            {
                "type": "when",
                "condition": "contains('${message}','HeartbeatResponse')",
                "action": "Ignore"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: It seems it was released 2 days after your comment :) https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.Logging/